# SYMFONY2 : ACL, Role and ClassScope

Tags: symfony, acl, role

I have a problem with the ACLs :

I use a class scope to grant permissions on Role.

This is my code to declare the ClassAce :

```
$objectIdentity = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity('class', 'Complete\\Class\\Name');
try
{
   $acl = $aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);
}
catch (\Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Exception\Exception $e)
{
   $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
}
// retrieving the security identity of the currently role
$securityIdentity = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\RoleSecurityIdentity($role);
// grant owner access
$acl->insertClassAce($securityIdentity, \Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Permission\MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
$aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
```

And this is my code to check access :

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
$oid = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity('class', 'Complete\\Class\\Name');
if (false === $securityContext->isGranted('EDIT', $oid))
{
   throw new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException();
}
```

I receive an AccessDeniedExeption, with the message in the logs : "No
ACL found for the object identity. Voting to deny access."

I can resolve this by changing the equals function of the
RoleSecurityIdentity

The original function is

```
public function equals(SecurityIdentityInterface $sid)
{
   if (!$sid instanceof RoleSecurityIdentity) {
       return false;
   }

   return $this->role === $sid->getRole();
}
```

But if I change it by

```
public function equals(SecurityIdentityInterface $sid)
{
   if (!$sid instanceof RoleSecurityIdentity) {
       return false;
   }

   return $this->role == $sid->getRole();
}
```

It works...

I use my Own Role Class, could it be a problem ?

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the similar problem. Extending Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role in my own Role class solved the problem.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role as CoreRole;

class Role extends CoreRole{ // or extends CoreRole implements RoleInterface
// my custom Role class
}
```

Find out what types of value are checking in equal function, it has to be string, not object. In my case it was role object.

Comment: Hi @anithaly is that role class a doctrine entity class ? i mean are you saving your roles in your database ? i have the same problem here, well i will try saving my roles into the databse anyway but i will apriciated if you can help me out here thanks.

Comment: i think i found the answer to my own question, the symfony documentation explains how to save roles into the database and also explains that you have to extend Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role, here is the link [Managing Roles in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database)